# how to create auto-generated file from last revision in Alembic

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, sqlalchemy-migrate

I'm following [this](http://flask-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) tutorial.. and the *initial* auto generate is perfect.. it basically creates the migration file with the upgrade and downgrade methods just fine.

so let's say this is the migration file's revision number: `3e96cf22770b`.. all of my upgrade statements look like this:

```
def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('hashtag',
                    sa.Column('id', sa.VARCHAR(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('text', sa.VARCHAR(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
                    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name=u'hashtag_pkey')
                    )
```

and my downgrade statement looks like this:

```
def downgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_table('user_access_token')
```

Now I made a simple modification to my models.py file, this is what it looks like on git:

```
-    verificationCode = Column(String())
+    isVerified = Column(Boolean())
```

The thing is, I have no idea how to run an autogenerate statement that actually just give me a *delta* migration file.. ie i just want a migration file that replaces one column by another..

i tried setting the current revision to `3e96cf22770b` then running

```
python migrate.py db revision --autogenerate
```

but then it keeps on creating duplicates of the initial migration file (ie migrating the entire database schema) rather than just the delta.. ideas?

Comment: Are you sure changing column types are supported?

Answer (score 1):

Alembic automatically generates a migration script (using the `--autogenerate` flag) by observing the current DB schema (it actually connects the DB and fetches the schema) and the new model (in your python code). So when you want to create a new migration script, make sure your database is at the previous schema (`3e96cf22770b` in your case).

Not sure how you tried to set the current schema, but you can check for the schema at `alembic_version` table in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run:

```
python migrate.py db migrate
```

and that should create a new migration file for you. Once you get that you can run:

```
python migrate.py db upgrade
```

and that will upgrade your database. 
Before you upgrade your db, look at the migration file and see if it's doing what you're wanting to do.

Comment: that's not my question at all

Comment: Well from the docs you linked to, it says the migrate.py db revision --autogenerate creates an empty migration script. From your question it looks like you want to remove the verificationCode column and add an isVerified column to the database table/schema, am I wrong?